# Is it possible/sensible to use an in-memory persistent store as a staging area, and if so how do I clear it?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

We've got some data coming into our app.  Sometimes it will be saved, so we've made an entity and a NSManagedObject subclass for it.  Usually, though, the objects will be instantiated and never saved.  I'm thinking of using another persistent store, with the NSInMemoryStoreType, as a staging area, then moving the ones we want to save into the sqlite store.  Is that possible/sensible?

If it is, I'd like to clear out the staging area every so often.  Is there a way to clear out just the objects assigned to the memory store?

Answer (score 1):

You should read this lengthy blog post on temporary Core Data objects.  It's very insightful.

http://www.cimgf.com/2011/08/08/transient-entities-and-core-data/

Answer (score 0):

Can you not use the 'scratch pad' / Undo Management properties of core data?
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/Articles/cdUsingMOs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001803-207821-TPXREF148

Comment: Not really - in order to transfer things between threads we need to save them to a persistent store.